# $\left(\cot^{-1}\left({-\sqrt{y-a}}\right)-\cot^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{\sqrt{y-a}}}\right)\right)\cdot\frac{2a}{{\pi}}={a}$

Tags: functions

I slightly modified the question that I posted earlier.If you enter my formula on a graphing calculator, you can notice that between the left and right sides of the equation there can be a sign of "greater than", "less than" or "equal to", and the result will always be the same. So the result will always be the same regardless of the sign between the left and right sides of the equation.
$$\left(\cot^{-1}\left({-\sqrt{y-a}}\right)-\cot^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{\sqrt{y-a}}}\right)\right)\cdot\frac{2a}{{\pi}}={a}$$ or
$$\left(\cot^{-1}\left({-\sqrt{y-a}}\right)-\cot^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{\sqrt{y-a}}}\right)\right)\cdot\frac{2a}{{\pi}}<{a}$$ or
$$\left(\cot^{-1}\left({-\sqrt{y-a}}\right)-\cot^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{\sqrt{y-a}}}\right)\right)\cdot\frac{2a}{{\pi}}>{a}$$
as I said, the result is the same in all three cases
the value $a$ can be $a=x$ or $a=x^2$ or $a=\frac{x}{2}$does not matter I am interested in another example of these or similar equations (the equation that has the previously described characteristic)?

.....

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\cot^{-1}\left({\sqrt{y-a}}\right)+\cot^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{\sqrt{y-a}}}\right)\right)=\frac{{\pi}}{2}$$ or

$$\left(\cot^{-1}\left({-\sqrt{y-a}}\right)-\cot^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{\sqrt{y-a}}}\right)\right)= -\frac{{\pi}}{2}$$

are trig ***identities*** valid for all values of $y$.

You can make up any trig formula from a right angled triangle like

$$ \sin^{-1} x +\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2} =\frac{{\pi}}{2}.$$

Comment: It is an arbitrary * cancellable* constant $a$ appearing on both sides of the identity ; it can be any  real number.